# v-autocomplete "search" for more information in the data slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a v-autocomplete like this:

```
            <v-autocomplete
              :items="hostproperties"
              label="Search Host Properties"
              prepend-icon="mdi-tune"
              item-text="propertyvalue"
              item-value="host_id"
              @change="showHost"
            >
              <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
                {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.name }} - {{ data.item.propertyvalue }} - {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.unit }}
              </template>
              <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
                {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.name }} - {{ data.item.propertyvalue }} - {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.unit }}
              </template>
            </v-autocomplete>
```

Everything works perfect.
But there is one thing I want to optimize.
In fact, when I currently type in the autocomplete field, it only searches in `item-text="propertyvalue"`.
Is there a way to tell the autocomplete to search in the slot data as well? So that also for

```
{{ data.item.hostpropertytype.name }}} - {{{ data.item.propertyvalue }} - {{{ data.item.hostpropertytype.unit }}
```

Can be searched?
I want to be able to search for the following fields:

```
hostpropertytype.name
propertyvalue
hostpropertytype.unit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#custom-filter-on-autocomplete), you might need to pass a `filter` method to your `v-autocomplete` which dictates the custom logic that you wanted.

On your `v-autocomplete`

```html
<v-autocomplete
  :items="hostproperties"
  :filter="filter"
  label="Search Host Properties"
  prepend-icon="mdi-tune"
  item-text="propertyvalue"
  item-value="host_id"
  @change="showHost"
>
  <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.name }} - {{ data.item.propertyvalue }} - {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.unit }}
  </template>
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
    {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.name }} - {{ data.item.propertyvalue }} - {{ data.item.hostpropertytype.unit }}
  </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

On your methods:

```js
showHost() {...},
filter(item, queryText, itemText) {
  const searchText = queryText.toLowerCase();

  // define your custom logic of your filter
  const name = item.hostpropertytype.name.toLowerCase();
  const value = item.propertyvalue.toString();
  const unit = item.hostpropertytype.unit.toString();

  return (
    name.indexOf(searchText) > -1 ||
    value.indexOf(searchText) > -1 ||
    unit.indexOf(searchText) > -1
  );
}
```

Here a sample demo of a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-curie-w5uev?file=/src/components/Playground.vue).